# Regular Expression to Locate unpaired quotation marks

Tags: regex

I've got CSV data as follows:

```
1,poster,1,20# Recycled Bond,"4/0, colour master",16.5x23.4",trim
,files in colour attachments COH001 - 2556712,,FSC,,,
8,"Tags (#1-5,7-9)",8,20# Recycled Bond,"4/0, colour master",7x3 ",trim
1,Tags (#6),1,20# Recycled Bond,"4/0, colour master",7x3,trim
,files in colour attachments COH001 - 2556712,,FSC,,,
```

I want to locate unpaired quotation marks and append a closing quote where there's one missing. For example, line #1 would go from *"4/0, colour master",16.5x23.4",trim* to *"4/0, colour master",16.5x23.4"",trim* (notice the extra double quote before *,trim*

Any ideas?

Comment: What if your field missing the quote also has an embedded comma?  Can we assume that will never happen?

Comment: Your field isn't missing a double quote - the double quote symbol here is the symbol for inches.

Comment: your example before and after doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: you could change inches symbol from doublequote `"` to double singlequote `''` to make it more convenient for the csv parser (instead of changing it to double doublequote `""`)

Comment: Mark, that's correct. I should have clarified that it's "orphaned" in the sense that it's not used to encapsulate a string; it's used to denote a unit of measure. It does however cause the CSV parser grief :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
s/(,[0-9.x ]*)",/\1'',/
```

or to make it slightly more universal,

```
s/((^|,)[0-9.x ]*)"(\s*(,|$))/\1''\3/
```